# npm issue on EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

I download and compiled node and npm on EC2 instance. Everything seems right (the -v are shown on both), but when I try to `npm install pm2` ask for me to run the command as Root (I am), yet when I `sudo npm install` says `sudo: npm: command not found`. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: did you try running as administrator? 
If it does not work then the command is for Linux.

Comment: Seems I can sudo everything besides this. Might be an issue with permissions.

Comment: This happens when you installed npm in a location only accessible in the PATH folder list for the user that installed it.  Try moving npm into something accessible in the sudo PATH (you can see that by running `sudo echo $PATH`

Comment: Note that Amazon Linux has node available so you could have just done `yum install nodejs.x86_64`. If the version in their repo is not the one you want then just use `n` to install the version of node you want (`npm install -g n`).

Answer (score 1):

This solved the issue.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/node /usr/lib/node
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
```